# clang-tidy by CLion and standalone yield different results

Tags: c++, clion, clang-tidy

I have clang-tidy enabled in CLion, using a certain version. I want to add clang-tidy to our CI (continuous integration) flow that runs as a standalone script. However, although clang-tidy version is the same and the config file (.clang-tidy) is the same, the results are different (partial match).
What could be the reason that same tool and same configuration generates different results?

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess, but could it be that one is formatting the entire file while the other is only formatting changed lines?

Comment: There must be some difference in the inputs that you haven't accounted for.

Comment: Could it be that you are running the tool on two different operating systems and that there are slight behaviour differences in that case?

Comment: Is the tool perhaps being invoked with different command line options or environment variables that could alter the behaviour in the two cases?

Comment: Although the tool version is the same in both cases, was it compiled identically? Could some defaults have been set different during compilation? Have custom modifications been made to either build?   Just guessing here, but it's something to check (as is the stuff in my other comments).

Comment: @JesperJuhl - No, CLion checks for the whole file. The OS and the binary of the tool are all the same

Comment: @ScottMcPeak- That is exactly what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: @Aaron ok, good to know. What about command line options and environment variables? Are they also identical?